# How to make two different Constructors in the same Class - Android

Tags: java, android, class, constructor, adapter

i think that this can be done, but maybe im wrong (Im sure im wrong). I have this adapter that sometimes uses a List of Class1 and in other moments uses a list of Class2. So, can i do TWO differents constructors where un the first one i use List1 and in the other one i use the List2?

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<String> listaDeTexto;
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<MetodoDePago> listaMetodosDePago;
private List<Banco> listaDeBancos;

public SpinnerAdapter(List<String> listaDeTexto, Activity activity, List<MetodoDePago> listaMetodosDePago) {
    this.listaDeTexto = listaDeTexto;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.listaMetodosDePago = listaMetodosDePago;
}

public SpinnerAdapter(List<String> listaDeTexto, Activity activity, List<Banco> listaDeBancos) {
    this.listaDeTexto = listaDeTexto;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.listaDeBancos = listaDeBancos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listaDeTexto.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_custom,null);
    }
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSpinner);
    textView.setText(listaDeTexto.get(position));

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgViewSpinner);
    Glide.with(view)
            .load(listaMetodosDePago.get(position).getThumbnail())
            .into(imageView);

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to type erasure in Java, you are basically declaring two constructors which look like, `SpinnerAdapter(List l1, Activity a, List l2) { }` to Java.

A simple solution would be to create one constructor and add a `type` argument. So, something like, `SpinnerAdapter(List l1, Activity a, List l2, int type) { }`.

You can then check the type value in the constructor and the `getView(...)` method to initialize your variables as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Just for now i created differents adaptors but i will try this.